# Python2.7 cx_Freeze missing module Controller

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze

When I execute the exe file created with cs_Freeze, i have this error :

```
Missing modules:
? Controleur imported from main__main__
? _emx_link imported from os
? ce imported from os
? fcntl imported from subprocess
? org.python.core imported from copy, pickle
? os.path imported from os, shlex
? os2 imported from os
? os2emxpath imported from os
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from posixpath
? riscos imported from os
? riscosenviron imported from os
? riscospath imported from os
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.
```

My setup.py :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('D:\\Python\\Microdurometre_Final\\main.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='Microdurometre',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'Logiciel de controle des microdurom\x8atres Leica et Matra',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables
      )
```

I know i have nothing in `packages` but if I add `Controleur` or `riscospath`, I have this error during the build : `ImportError: No module named 'Controleur'`

Comment: Where is `Controleur` module located (it seems to be imported in _main.py_)? Since it runs (if it runs) then you must have added it in _PYTHONPATH_.

Comment: `Controleur` is located here inside the project : `src\Controleur\Controleur.py`
And yes, it's imported from main.py

Comment: I'm not sure neither if it'll work nor if it's recommended: modify _setup.py_ and add `import sys` (at the beginning) and then `sys.path.append(${PATH_TO_SRC_FOLDER})` (before the  `setup` call). How does the `import` statement from _main.py_ look like?

Comment: It work. But now I have other errors :/ `Importerror: No module named Modele.Position`
If i add `...\\modele` to the path, same error.

Comment: You are aware that I'm not familiar with your project structure :)... Anyway, if the project works let's say when you manually invoke _main.py_, you must duplicate the (_Python_ specific) environment in _setup.py_, meaning that all the settings (e.g. _PYTHONPATH_ variable set in the environment or in some sort of a project file), should be set to the same values when running _setup.py_.

Comment: Ok :D Here is the structure of my project : https://pastebin.com/yH7yVGUk
Yes my project is working on PyCharm :) And here is my main.py https://pastebin.com/JWeZW6Nv

Comment: Did you try printing `sys.path` from your _main.py_ file, before importing `Controleur`? I suspect something related to relative imports. Could you change them (e.g. the `src` related one to `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "src"))`)?

Comment: I have change the 2 `import`
and here is my `sys.path` https://pastebin.com/GiLbiQtF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144929/discussion-between-cristifati-and-mike-thomson).